# How to render current time in JSF every second by @Schedule

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

My problem is that i don't know how to render current time in jsf every second. I have a bean:

```
@Schedule(second="*",minute="*",hour="*")
public void showTime() {
    date = new Date();
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

And i can only render current time by clicking button. I would like to render it every second without clicking.

Maybe there is better way to do it instead of using @Schedule and java.util.Date. Thanks in advance.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use JS function on the client side for that?

Comment: @BalusC the linked duplicate is misleading because of the comment above me. Trance I don't think you want to change the time via ajax.